# How to redirect to html page from servlet

Tags: html, servlets

Here is my code :

```
if("Plot Data".equals(action))

{

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        response.sendRedirect("plot_sat.html?"+plotpath+"#"+linkname
}
```

Before the executin of `IF statement`, I am closing the connection of `servlet` `with matlab`( which I have used in the code).
The output of the matlab should be redirected to the page `plot_sat.html` But instead it is redirected to the same page.
The value of **plotpath** and **linkname** are the ones which appear in the url.

Please Help !
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you seeing an `IllegalStateException` in server logs?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Finding the server log file? Opening the server log file? Reading the server log file? Finding IllegalStateException in there?